# PDAL diff execution

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have two point clouds one is of an area before development, one is after.

I want to isolate the land surface points (A) now under the new buildings and I want to isolate the new buildings (B).

So I see PDAL has a diff function, would this enable me to export A and B as described above?

I would also like to add a +/- of 10cm to the selection, is this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the intent of `pdal diff`. According to https://www.pdal.io/apps/diff.html:

> The command checks for the equivalence of the following items:
>
> - Different schema
> - Expected count
> - Metadata
> - Actual point count
> - Byte-by-byte point data

A separate PDAL kernel would be required for what you are looking to do.